# Building Dimensions (Lagrange Multipliers) (Optimization Problem)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> A rectangular building is to have a volume of $8000ft^3$.  Annual heating and cooling costs will amount to $\$2/ft^2$ for its top, front, and back, and $\$4/ft^2$ for the two end walls.  What dimensions of the building would minimize these annual costs?

I have attached my work so far.  However, I end up with a system that I don't know how to solve.  Is there any easy way to solve this that I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solve your first three equations for $\lambda$ and make two equations out of those three equations by eliminating $\lambda$.

Then you have three equations and three unknown which you can solve for the dimensions.